# Безопасность авторизации: приложение на ANDROID + SERVER PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, android, android-studio, безопасность, авторизация

Сильно не пинайте , первый раз делаю авторизацию через android!
Есть android приложение. Данные передаются/принимаются через POST/GET в MySQL.
Как сделать безопасную авторизацию:

1. Сейчас пароль вводится в приложение, отправляется на сервер PHP и
   шифруется  с помощью md5 и sha1 , сверяется с паролем в БД, если ок -
   мы авторизовались. Вопрос дальше ...при каждой отправке или получении
   данных в приложении тоже нужно авторизоваться?
2. SSL-сертификат, подключают ли такое дело для безопасности в android приложениях?
3. Если есть еще какие либо методы безопасности буду благодарен подсказке.

Comment: md5 и sha1 выкидываем из хеширования пароля и используем password_hash() и password_verify() для этой цели в php.

Comment: Во время передачи перехватываем пароль и угоняем аккаунт

Comment: если возможно перехватить как защищать? с этим и была создана тема..предложите варианты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Посмотрите в сторону токенов. На сервере работает веб-сервис, который генерирует токены, и после успешной авторизации выдает токен, который живет несколько минут, потом протухает. В следующем запросе уже проверяйте токен.
2. На собственном опыте столкнулся - выписанный сертификат в доверенном центре сертификации, но java генерирует ошибку **Trust anchor for certification path not found**. Поэтому пришлось обходить данные "грабли", хоть есть и сертифкат.
3. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841572/md5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE?noredirect=1#comment1349780_841572) мне подсказывают, что лучше использовать sha-512