# MD5 устарел, что использовать вместо?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, хеширование, md5

MD5 устарел, какую систему хэширования паролей использовать вместо устаревшей? Как вариант, создание динамической соли, это понятно. На дворе 2018 год, может уже какие-то новые способы появились?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да понял, был неправ.

Comment: Из криптографических  хешей сейчас используются различные SHA. в linux например для паролей используется SHA-512

Comment: Наверно стоит ориентироваться на SHA-3

Comment: @Mike, sha-512 безопаснее, чем md5 с динамической солью, как считаете?

Comment: @IvanVovk Ну google на суперкомпьютере уже смог создать измененное сообщение с таким же md5 как у оригинала. так что под конкрентный md5 получить любую подходящую последовательность байт уже вполне возможно при наличии ресурсов. для sha этого пока никто не сделал. И соль в unix системах при работе с sha-512 так же используется. Собственно она нужна только для защиты от подбора по готовому словарю

Comment: @Mike, оформляйте ответ!)

Comment: @IvanVovk а вы что, вместе с sha-512 динамическую соль использовать не собираетесь? :-)

Comment: @Mike ну, атака второго прообраза - не то чего следует бояться при хранении паролей :-) Какой прок злоумышленнику с возможности создать измененный пароль зная исходный?

Comment: PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, Argon2i

Comment: Конкретно в php следует просто не выпендриваться и использовать функцию password_hash (внутри неё по умолчанию bcrypt вроде бы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Актуальной криптостойкой хеш-функцией на момент написания этого ответа является SHA-3.

Но для хеширования паролей ее лучше не использовать: она слишком быстрая. Для паролей следует применять scrypt.

Comment: спасибо! А можете подсказать, как ее используете?

Comment: @IvanVovk нет, не могу. Потому что не использую. Как-то еще ни разу не приходилось делать проверку пароля :-)